# What is the difference and relationship between mpirun, mpiexec and mpiexec.hydra?

Tags: mpi

I got confused about 3 things: mpirun, mpiexec and mpiexec.hydra

On my cluster, all of them exist, and all of them belong to intel.

What is the difference and relationship between them? Especially, what on earth is mpiexec.hydra? Why there is a dot between mpiexec and hydra, what does it mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best advance of Hydra MPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091397/whats-the-best-advance-of-hydra-mpi)

Comment: @JohnZwinck Hi, JohnZwinck. I don't think so. I know that post, but after reading it, I still don't understand. So I made this post

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`mpirun` and `mpiexec` are basically the same - the name of the process launcher in many MPI implementations. The MPI standard says nothing about how the ranks should be started and controlled, but it recommends (though does not demand) that, if there is a launcher of any kind, it should be named `mpiexec`. Some MPI implementations started with `mpirun`, then adopted `mpiexec` for compatibility. Other implementations did the reverse. In the end, most implementations provide their launcher under both names. In practice, there should be no difference in what `mpirun` and `mpiexec` do.

Different MPI implementations have different means of launching and controlling the processes. MPICH started with an infrastructure called MPD (Multi-Purpose Daemon or something). Then it switched to the newer Hydra process manager. Since Hydra does things differently than MPD, the Hydra-based `mpiexec` takes different command-line arguments than the MPD-based one and to make it possible for users to explicitly select the Hydra-based one, it is made available as `mpiexec.hydra`. The old one is called `mpiexec.mpd`. It is possible to have an MPICH-based MPI library that only provides the Hydra launcher and then `mpiexec` and `mpiexec.hydra` will be the same executable. Intel MPI is based on MPICH and its newer versions use the Hydra process manager.

Open MPI is built on top of Open Run-Time Environment (ORTE) and its own process launcher is called `orterun`. For compatibility, `orterun` is also symlinked as `mpirun` and `mpiexec`.

To summarise:

- `mpiexec.something` is a specific version of the MPI process launcher for a given implementation
- `mpiexec` and `mpirun` are the generic names, usually copies of or symbolic links to the actual launcher
- both `mpiexec` and `mpirun` should do the same
- some implementations name their launcher `mpiexec`, some name it `mpirun`, some name it both, and that is often the source of confusion when more than one MPI implementations are simultaneously available in the system paths (e.g. when installed from distro packages)

Comment: Thank you so much, Hristo Iliev. Your answer makes things much clearer. And it seems that `mpirun` must specify `-n` options, while `mpiexec` and `mpiexec.hydra` doesn't have to be

Comment: On my Knights Landing system with the Intel compiler `mpiexec` is a symbolic link to `mpiexec.hydra` (i.e. they are the same). However, `mpirun` is a shell script which calls mpiexec.hydra.

Comment: What does your sentence "both mpiexec and mpirun should do the same" mean? You mean they should do the same *thing*?

Comment: It means both are launching an MPI job in one way or another.